# DataTable not filtering newly inserted data properly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

For reference, I am using DataTable.js version 1.10.21 and DataTables Select version 1.3.1

I have created a DataTable with a "Status" column that can be updated. This column also has a filter on it. The filter works perfectly after initial load of the table but after a cell in the status column has been changed, the filter doesn't seem to be seeing the updated data but, instead, still filters on the old data.

This is the js that is being used to update a particular cell in the status column:
NOTE: We've simplified the example to eliminate code that isn't an issue.

```
var row = document.getElementById("user-id-" + userId);
statusColumn = row.children[4];
statusColumn.innerText = "inactive";
setTimeout(function(){ 
   $('.dataTable').DataTable().reload();
},2000);
```

I have attempted to use the reload(), draw(), and re-initializing the entire table using dataTable(). None of functions allows the table to filter correctly with the new value. The filter does work but it filters based on the old value that no longer exists in the table.

Below are two screenshots as a visual example.

- 1st screenshot: Me looking at newly loaded table and me filtering on the status "active.
- I am then going to change Aaron McClendon (first row) to "inactive".
- 2nd screenshot: Me searching on the status "active" again. Aaron should no longer show up since he is now "inactive" but as you can see he does show in the "active" status filter yet his status has been changed to "inactive".
- Filtering to other statuses and coming back does not change the results and the only way to begin filtering correctly on the updated data is by reloading the page.

[Newly loaded table while filtering on the active status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6DOr.png)

[After updating Aaron McClendon and filtering on the active status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ck7KS.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the data of the cell using the api: https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().data()

It's difficult to give a detailed answer since you didn't post any of the html markup or enough of your javascript, but based on what you provided, it's probably something like this:

```
var table = $('.dataTable').DataTable();
var row = document.getElementById("user-id-" + userId);
var statusColumn = row.children[4];
var cell = table.cell( statusColumn );
cell.data( "inactive" ).draw();
```